# Almost all audio-related functions are failing (iPhone 7)

Tags: iphone

When placing calls, I can’t hear the other person and they can’t hear me. The calls go through and can be answered but neither side can be heard. If I try and use voice memos, I can’t even begin recording. Any app that makes calls such as FaceTime or Facebook messenger fails if I try and call or answer a call. If I try and restart my phone, it gets stuck on the Apple that comes up when turning on for hours at a time. I’ve tried resetting, and updating and neither option has fixed the issue, just led to more hours stuck on the “Apple screen”. Apart from the audio and reboot issue, all other functions of the phone are working.

Answer (score 3):

If you've tried restarting, updating, and factory resetting and have had no luck fixing the issues, you may need to send your phone in to Apple for repair. Getting stuck on the Apple screen for hours, even after reset, leads me to believe it's a logic board issue. [Personal repair may be expensive, difficult, and will cause damage to the waterproof seal.](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+7+Logic+Board+Replacement/76050)